# Diablo II LOD How to change difficulty levels online?

Tags: battle.net, diablo-ii

I'm currently stuck in hell mode with an lvl 56 character, how do I get back to nightmare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you're in Hell difficulty, you'll only see Games that are on that difficulty. You can create a Nightmare game by yourself any time however... or ask a friend who is in Nightmare difficulty if he could tell you the name of an open NM game.

Comment: That's stupid, I mean I don't belong in hell diff yet :( Not cool... but thanks for the answer

Comment: Yeah I agree. You should try to stay in NM until about level 70-75. For your next character: If you're in a party that's going to kill baal and the person that created the game hasn't completed the quest yet (you'll see that in the quest log), leave the party before they kill baal. That way you're sure to stay in nightmare difficulty.